# AutoIt Firefox Automation - _FFClick doesn't work on buttons anymore? (FF.au3)

Tags: autoit

Help! I had AutoIt code that would do the following:

1. **load a page in FireFox**, then
2. **click on the 'browse' button,** then
3. **waits for the File Upload window to appear**

This code worked great and I used it many times! Now, ***about a month later, it stopped working***. I checked the HTML page and it did NOT change, and the id is the same.

Here are some resources:

- [_FFOpenURL](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/ff_functions/_FFOpenURL.php)
- [_FFLoadWait](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/ff_functions/_FFLoadWait.php)
- [_FFClick](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/ff_functions/_FFClick.php)
- [WinWaitActive](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWaitActive.htm)
- [ControlClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm)
- [Full list of FF.au3 functions](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/)

Here is the **HTML that I am trying to access**. I am trying to click on `#filename`

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Import step one: upload Word Document</legend>
    <h2>Import Word Document: Upload</h2>
    <div class="field-group">
         <div class="checkbox/radio">
              <label for="filename">Upload:</label>
              <input id="filename" name="filename" size="50" "="" type="file">
         </div>
     </div>
     <input class="text hidden" name="pageId" value="158367782">
      <div class="buttons-container">
           <div class="buttons">
                <span class="word-file-loading hidden" id="loading">Loading</span>
                <input disabled="disabled" id="next" name="submit" value="Next" class="button" type="submit">
           </div>
      </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here's my **simplified AutoIt code** that should press the `#filename` button:

```vb
; 1) OPEN THE PAGE (WORKS) (I changed the URL)
    _FFOpenURL("http://..../")

; 2) WAIT FOR PAGE TO LOAD (WORKS)
    _FFLoadWait()

; 3) SLEEP FOR 5 SECONDS (WORKS)
    Sleep(5000)

; 4) CLICK THE BROWSE BUTTON (FAILS)
;    (SAYS IT IS A SUCCESS BUT THE BUTTON NEVER GETS PRESSED!!)
    _FFClick("filename", "id")

; 5) WAIT FOR "FILE UPLOAD" WINDOW TO APPEAR (FAILS)
;    (FAILS BECAUSE BUTTON NEVER GOT PRESSED ABOVE)
    Local $result = WinWaitActive("File Upload","",10)
```

Here is my **full autoit code** that should press the `#filename` button:

```vb
; 1) OPEN THE PAGE (WORKS)
    If _FFOpenURL("http://..../") Then
        FileWrite($log,"[INFO] Opened Page successfully." & @CRLF)
    Else
       FileWrite($log,"[ERROR] Could not open Page." & @error & " Extended Error Code = " & @extended  & @CRLF)
       MsgBox(0, "Error", "Could not open Page.")
       Exit
    EndIf

; 2) WAIT FOR PAGE TO LOAD (WORKS)
    If _FFLoadWait() Then
        FileWrite($log,"[INFO] Waited to open page successfully." & @CRLF)
    Else
        FileWrite($log,"[ERROR] Could not wait for Page." & @error & " Extended Error Code = " & @extended  & @CRLF)
        MsgBox(0, "Error", "Could not wait for Page.")
        Exit
    EndIf

; 3) SLEEP FOR 5 SECONDS 
    Sleep(5000)

; 4) CLICK THE BROWSE BUTTON 
;    (SAYS IT IS A SUCCESS BUT THE BUTTON NEVER GETS PRESSED!!)
    ;Click the "Choose File" button
    If _FFClick("filename", "id") Then
        FileWrite($log,"[INFO] Clicked the 'browse' button successfully." & @CRLF)
    Else
        FileWrite($log,"[ERROR] Could not click the 'browse' button." & @error & " Extended Error Code = " & @extended  & @CRLF)
        MsgBox(0, "Error", "Could not click the 'browse' button.")
        Exit
    EndIf

; 5) WAIT FOR "FILE UPLOAD" WINDOW TO APPEAR
;    (FAILS BECAUSE BUTTON NEVER GOT PRESSED ABOVE)

    ;Wait for the file upload dialog to appear
    Local $result = WinWaitActive("File Upload","",10) ;Wait 10 seconds for "File Upload" window to appear
    If $result == 0 Then
       FileWrite($log,"[ERROR] Waited for 'File Upload' to show, but it never did. " & @error & " Extended Error Code = " & @extended  & @CRLF)
       MsgBox(0, "Error", " Waited for 'File Upload' to show, but it never did. ")
       Exit
    Else
       FileWrite($log,"[INFO] Opened 'File Upload' dialog successfully. " & @CRLF)
    EndIf
```

Here is the errors shown from the Scite console (I replaced the URL):

```
_FFOpenURL: http://...
__FFSend: try{window.content.top.document.location.href='http://...'}catch(e){'_FFCmd_Err';};
__FFRecv: http://...
_FFLoadWait: ....... loaded in 1688ms
[object HTMLDocument] - {pagetreesearchform: {...}, location: {...}, getElementsByName: function() {...}, getItems: function() {...}, open: function() {...}, close: function() {...}, write: function() {...}, ...}
__FFSend: FFau3.WCD=window.content.top.document;
__FFRecv: [object HTMLDocument] - {pagetreesearchform: {...}, location: {...}, getElementsByName: function() {...}, getItems: function() {...}, open: function() {...}, close: function() {...}, write: function() {...}, ...}
[object HTMLDocument] - {pagetreesearchform: {...}, location: {...}, getElementsByName: function() {...}, getItems: function() {...}, open: function() {...}, close: function() {...}, write: function() {...}, ...}
_FFLoadWait: . loaded in 83ms
[object HTMLDocument] - {pagetreesearchform: {...}, location: {...}, getElementsByName: function() {...}, getItems: function() {...}, open: function() {...}, close: function() {...}, write: function() {...}, ...}
__FFSend: try{FFau3.simulateEvent(FFau3.WCD.getElementById('filename'),'MouseEvents','click');}catch(e){'_FFCmd_Err';};
__FFRecv: 1
_FFLoadWait: . loaded in 11ms
[object HTMLDocument] - {pagetreesearchform: {...}, location: {...}, getElementsByName: function() {...}, getItems: function() {...}, open: function() {...}, close: function() {...}, write: function() {...}, ...}
+>11:56:43 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0
+>11:56:43 AutoIt3Wrapper Finished.
```

And here is my version information:

- [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) v3.3.14.2
- [SciTE](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/) v3.6.0
- Firefox v44.0.2
- [Firefox AutoIt Plugin](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/) - FF V0.6.0.1b-15.au3 ([Docs](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/))
- Firefox Plugin for using AutoIt - [MozRepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl) 1.1.2.1